# How to unlink OneDrive on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, onedrive

I have two accounts, one account which has a OneDrive linked to it, this Microsoft account holds all of my data on OneDrive.
I have just installed and activated Windows 8.1 using a new outlook address, but I would like to use my OneDrive which is linked to my "old" outlook address.
How can I unlink my OneDrive, and log in with the "older" Microsoft account to use OneDrive?
I am using that address on my laptop, and since the "sync your wallpapers, color settings" etc. is irritating me I would not like to use the same Microsoft account on my desktop as well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the account you use with OneDrive, but you can't use the folder with multiple accounts at the same time.

To change the account you use with OneDrive

Right-click the OneDrive icon (The OneDrive icon) in the notification area, at the far right of the taskbar, and then click Settings.
On the Settings tab, click Unlink OneDrive.

Restart OneDrive and sign in with the account you want to use. You'll need to select the location for your OneDrive folder again. If you select the same location, the folders for both accounts will be merged. If the PC had the Fetch files feature turned on, you'll need to turn it on again.

More at the [FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/windows-app-faq)

Comment: you are incorrect when a user is signed into windows 8.1 it forces the signed in user account. It does not give you the settings option. Please read the question fully next time.

Comment: @TomEus - This answer does not seem to apply to `Windows 8.1`  The support article does not apply to `Windows 8.1`.

Comment: I tested this out, and it didn't work. the "Unlink OneDrive" option wasn't there.

Answer (score 4):

The OneDrive icon in the notification area doesn't give the option settings. So sadly there
is no way to change your account.

Comment: Office.com has a support [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OneDrive-desktop-app-for-Windows-850703dd-ea56-4c7a-bff5-6c2e4da227cf) for changing accounts, but the buttons/links it says to use are no longer present in the OneDrive options, at least on my Windows 8.1 box.

Answer (score 2):

From the [OneDrive: FAQ  for Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-8/onedrive-app-faq):

> **Can I sign in with a different account to browse a different OneDrive?**
>
> You can't switch between accounts in the OneDrive app. When you sign in to a PC with your Microsoft account, you're automatically signed in to OneDrive with that account. You can still get to OneDrive files for a different account by going to the OneDrive website.