# How can I manage resource use by OneDrive for Business (GROOVE.EXE)?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I switched to OneDrive for Business about 1.5-2 months ago, when MS decided to change free OneDrive personal storage from 25 gb to 5 gb. I did notice a performance hit, but it was small enough that I was willing to live with it in exchange for cloud storage. This morning, however, Autodesk Inventor ( a parametric cad package) became so slow as to be unusable. Killing the GROOVE.EXE process resolved the situation immediately. I did keep the inventor project (the files I was working on) in my sync folder, but I did the same thing with OneDrive Personal and never had any problems like this.

Is there some way to control the behavior of GROOVE.EXE to keep it from hogging resources like this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer to your question [At this site](http://teqsnacks.com/2014/09/15/microsoft-onedrive-for-business-high-cpu-load/)

[Download and install a fresh new copy of Onedrive for Business](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2903984)

[Run the Onedrive Troubleshooter](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-onedrive-troubleshooter-fix-your-problems) to make sure there are no issues

Clear the office cache.

For that last step, follow the instructions from “Why is OneDrive for Business always using 25% CPU?” :

```
==============================================

1. Right click on the Windows status bar, select Start Task Manager, and get a list of running processes as follows:

    If you’re running Windows 7: Select the Processes tab.
    If you’re running Windows 8: Select More Details in the bottom left and then select the Details tab.

2. Verify that none of the following processes are running:

    groove.exe
    msosync.exe
    msouc.exe
    winword.exe
    excel.exe
    powerpnt.exe

3. If any of the processes above are running, stop the process by right-clicking it and selecting End Process.

4. Give yourself an administrator role as follows:

    If you’re running Windows 7: Click the start button and type cmd in the search bar. When cmd.exe appears in the results, right-click it and select Run as Administrator.
    If you’re running Windows 8: Drag your mouse to the bottom left corner of the screen, right click on the Start icon that appears, and then select Command Prompt (Admin).

5. At the command prompt, delete the Office file cache and Spw folders by issuing four commands as follows:

a. Type this and then press the Enter key:
cd %USERPROFILE%AppDataLocalMicrosoftOffice15.0
1

cd %USERPROFILE%AppDataLocalMicrosoftOffice15.0

b. Type this and then press the Enter key:
rmdir OfficeFileCache /s
1

rmdir OfficeFileCache /s

c. Type this and then press the Enter key:
cd %USERPROFILE%AppDataLocalMicrosoftOffice
1

cd %USERPROFILE%AppDataLocalMicrosoftOffice

d. Type this and then press the Enter key:
rmdir Spw /s
1

rmdir Spw /s

6. If you get an error when executing either rmdir command (steps b or d), one of the .exe processes is probably still running. Fix the problem by returning to the Task Manager (step 2), stopping the processes, and then removing the directories as described previously.

7. Remove the excess folders or files from your local SkyDrive Pro folder, and add them in smaller groups, according to the guidance at the top of this table.  
==============================================
```

Hope this helps, It checks the Groove.exe is running and aims to control the cpu.

Here is some advice from this site, [Re: cpu 100%](http://www.textndata.com/forums/cpu-100-a-4591.html)

As you know, Groove is constantly listening for and processing changes to
the shared spaces of which you are a member. The longer Groove is offline,
the more changes have been queued up. When Groove is first brought back
online it is likely to consume more memory than usual while it processes the
queued deltas. The performance will improve once Groove catches up on the
queue. The time and memory consumption depends on the changes being made,
especially for the file sharing workspaces (GFS).

```
 So, please check the following trouble shooting steps:
```

1. Make sure that the end user is using the latest version of Groove.
   Click Help>About Groove to check whether the build is 3.1a 2374. If the
   build number is lower, please visit the following URL to get the latest one:
   http://www.groove.net/downloads/groove/download-preview.cfm and try to
   install it again.
2. Use Grooveclean tool with the -all option to clean and rebuild the
   session between the groove client and it's Groove Relay server.

Note: You need to restore your account after that. So, backup your data is
important:
How to back up accounts and workspaces in Groove
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=907230

Here is a link to a Technote that will show you how to run a GrooveClean -all:
http://www.groove.net/support/kb/detail.cfm/docnum/TCN-00421

3. Please understand that the reason for Groove occupying high CPU resource
   is that there must be some workspaces need to synchronize when we start the
   Groove.

a. Please check all the workspaces which contain File Tool and the Groove
Folder Synchronization Spaces.
b. For the File Tool workspace, Please make sure that all of your files are
set to "Manual Download" and not automatic.See:
http://docs.groove.net/htmldocs/guide/tools/general/doentshare/files3x_download_settings.htm
or https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/groove
c. Please read over the FAQ's for GFS spaces carefully as the type, size,
and number of files in these spaces can cause sever performance issues:
http://www.groove.net/index.cfm?pagename=GFS_FAQ

If there are suspected workspace, please make sure others are works fine in
them and temporary delete them and restart Groove to test this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of providing an answer which doesn't exactly answer your question... But I hope someone might still be interested...

You can use OneDrive for business accounts with the normal Personal OneDrive application. I've never seen any performance problems doing it this way.

Comment: You mean, by rolling over my entire os to that account? This is a school account, and I assume it will go away after I graduate. Unless I am told otherwise, a non-starter.

Comment: Sign into the OneDrive desktop application using your OneDrive for Business credentials, that is all, instead of using the OneDrive for Business desktop app, which seems to be really buggy

Comment: win8.1 does not support this.

http://superuser.com/questions/719095/how-to-unlink-onedrive-on-windows-8-1

Comment: sorry, didnt see the tag.